# Use login user credentials for wired 802.1X authentication

Tags: networking, login, authentication, wired

I really need help on this one. I've lurked through all over Internet looking for a way to get multiple users, login with their own credentials,for a 802.1X authentication before login into the system. All I could find is a solution like this but with user credentials hard coded I mean, I cannot login in the same machine with 2 different users, because only one has the right credentials. I hope I'm not being a noob here, and I could really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After much dig i found this, hope this can help people in the future.

https://github.com/ehbello/pam-8021x